# Spark Scala Join dataframe not working as select

Tags: scala, apache-spark

The input data has the following rows:

```
2017043008,21655065096,2017-04-30 08:03:54,56.0,0,2,2017-04-30 08:04:50,21625368946
2017043021,21621452483,2017-04-30 21:43:41,105.0,0,2,2017-04-30 21:45:26,21625672898
2017043018,21629237860,2017-04-30 18:01:28,337.0,0,2,2017-04-30 18:07:05,21628741975
```

Code is:

```
val schema = new StructType().add(StructField("call_id", StringType, true)).
add(StructField("o_msisdn", StringType, true)). 
add(StructField("call_start_time", StringType, true)).
add(StructField("duration", FloatType, true)).
add(StructField("o_call_id", StringType, true)).
add(StructField("call_type", StringType, true)). 
add(StructField("call_end_time",StringType, true)). 
add(StructField("s_msisdn", StringType, true))


val callRows = callData.map(line => line.split(",").map(_.trim))
val rdd = callRows.map(row => 
  Row(row(0),row(1),row(2),row(3),row(4),row(5),row(6),row(7)))

val callsDataDF= sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd, schema)
```

The above dataframe is grouped using the following:

```
val groupedCalls = callsDataDF.groupBy($"s_msisdn", $"o_msisdn")
                     .agg(count($"call_id").as("count"))
                     .filter("count >3")

val callsDF = callsDataDF.toDF
val groupedDF = groupedCalls.toDF
```

Join the two dataframes, to get the row thats has `dataFrame1.col5 == dataFrame2.col6`

```
val res1 = callsDataDF.join(groupedDF, 
                callsDataDF("s_msisdn") === groupedDF("o_msisdn"))
```

The problem is this gives output with 0 rows, which is incorrect.

The following code gives the correct result

```
callsDataDF.registerTempTable("calls")
groupedCalls.registerTempTable("grouped")

sqlContext.sql("""select calls.*, grouped.o_msisdn, grouped.count 
from calls join grouped on calls.s_msisdn=grouped.o_msisdn""").show()
```

My question is why does the sql variant give the correct result, and not the scala join.

Comment: please add the definition of `schema` to make this example verifiable - currently it's hard to tell which field is which...

Comment: Schema has been added to the code.

Comment: In the example you supplied (the 3 records above) - no record survives the `filter("count >3")` (because there's no group with more than 3 records - even if we grouped all records together...), and even if that's removed - there's no value in `o_msisdn` that equals any value in `s_msisdn` - so the result _should_ be empty. Please provide an example that actually exemplifies the issue (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)